# How can i limit wordpress post title characters in sidebar?

Tags: themes, css

in wordpress template sidebar and recent posts or recent comments blocks:

when title has more than 30 characters new line created and its not good display

you can see this image for understand what i say:

[image]

style for side bar ul li is :

```
#body-right ul li a {
  background: url("../images/blog-point1.png") no-repeat scroll 8px center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: #45484A;
  display: block;
  font: 13px/28px 'OpenSansRegular',Arial,sans-serif;
  padding-left: 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

sidebar style:
#body-right ul li {
  background: url("../images/blog-body-right-line.png") no-repeat scroll center bottom rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  direction: rtl;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  list-style: none outside none;
  text-align: right;
}
```

So how can i solve this problem?

Comment: This is a better question for [wordpress.se].

Comment: @MattBall Thanks for edit and image but i need 10 rep to use image

Comment: @MattBall how can i move this question to wordpress section

Comment: Simplest way: delete this question and re-ask over there.

Comment: once i delete my post and ban from site and can not ask questions

Comment: What function are you calling to get the sidebar?

Comment: @Daniel: <div id="body-right">
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
  </div>

Comment: Ok. What is in sidebar.php then?

Comment: @Daniel: <?php
     if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar')) : // Each sidebar name ?>
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: Please update the question with the appropriate code that outputs the sidebar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i change body-right css

height:28px; to min-height:28px; and problem solved

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP [substr function](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php) but you have to think that there is no regular text string like that, you should try with some [loren ipsum](http://www.lipsum.com) simulator to do that